# Experiment using a laser beam

Tags: soft-question, laser, education

I need to come up with an experiment to conduct for my physics class. So far, I'm stuck at the use of lasers. What plausible experiments can be done using lasers that haven't been done before, and would be at the level of high school physics?(I'm a high school physics student with no access to expensive equipment: for starters, we don't even have digital ammeters or voltmeters).

Comment: You might want to ask this [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). However note that the chat room is quiet at the moment. If you want to pursue this the best time to ask is mid-afternoon UTC i.e. mid morning in the US/mid afternoon in Europe.

Comment: Probably you can't make an experiment which wasn't made before. But you can make an experiment which will be found quite interesting by your teacher / classmates. My first 2 tips would be: 1) some interference-based trick 2) some general relativity-based trick (for the second, you probably can't make enough accurate setting). I suggest to try the chat.

Comment: @peterh: You have a general relativity high school experiment (not involving a GPS receiver)???? I want to hear about that. Would you mind explaining it in the chat room?

Comment: @CuriousOne I think on two vertical laser beams with the same wavelength, directed against eachother, and measuring the gravitational redshift by their interference. But I wrote, his school lab experiment will probably not enough accurate for that. (Ext: now I am not even sure it would theoretically work).

Comment: @peterh: Oh, OK... no, I am sure that won't fly. I am not sure what it takes to make that work, but it's more NIST level stuff than high school... One could, theoretically, do a Pound-Rebka experiment in a high school setting, but that would take very dedicated teachers and students. Analyzing GPS low level data is probably a better shot at something like that, but the math is nowhere near high school level, I am afraid. I think the interference experiments are a good idea, though. There are tons of variations.

Comment: @CuriousOne I think it would be an interesting challenge even electronically, GPS chips don't really like to say the raw data as I know. This psychotic secretivity can be found in the GSM world, too.

Comment: @peterh: I have seen a few analyses on the internet, but you are right, not every chipset contains the required APIs... it's hacking and physics combined, I think. :-) When I was a teenager I built a DCF 77 receiver, but that is a trivial protocol compared to GPS... but building a GPS receiver from scratch would be a great high school project for the most gifted kids.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  You do not specify what equipment you have available or could obtain, only the ones you don't have - which is a tough restriction.  Do you even have a laser? If so, what kind? My advice is to speak with your science teacher about this. If he/she cannot suggest anything try searching the internet for school projects.  Asking for something which hasn't been done before is a tall order. Best to find a project which has been done before and make it better.

Comment: @peterh I keep a fairly close eye on reasonable cost atomic clocks and the like as I'd love to come up with a GR experiment for children. By low cost, I mean under a thousand or so dollars so that one could find some educational grant. No commercial atomic clock comes remotely near to what would be needed as yet. A variation on the Hafele Keating experiment for when school teams travel interstate and back might be doable in the next decade - but can you imagine the problems a homemade atomic clock with a controller board would raise in airport security!!?

Comment: @CuriousOne I've looked at GPS too as I'd love to come up with a GTR experiment for children. As far as I can make out, the only real option is to build your own receiver pretty much from scratch, with a not too trivial A/D and then build a system in your computer with one of the open source GPS software libraries around. All the chips I've looked at give you pure latitude / longitude - you can't get at the raw timing data at all. Garmin claim you can call for raw data through their API, but you have to pay a small fortune for them for a license to use their premium API.

Comment: The bulk of the experiment in optics that make use of interference or diffraction are easier with a laser as a source than with some broadband source and a pin hole.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: Yeah... building a receiver from scratch, especially without a $50-100K Vector network/spectrum analyzer in the lab, that's definitely _not_ for children, unless the definition of child has changed to "small, young genius". I never looked into the API issue, but I have heard that there are hacks. Even then working from the raw data is beyond a typical teenagers' ability, I would say. I think experiments that teach physics more "hands on" would be more suited.

Comment: @dmckee: The main difference with diffraction is that one needs a really dark room to see the effects well, OTOH, using a white light source gives very nice color effects _and_ it's speckle free, which I always find distracting with laser sources. It would be interesting to see how much fun one could have with LEDs, which may combine the best of both.